# Link Multiple URLs, Pattern Matcher

Tags: android, html, regex

I can not figure out how to handle multiple URL's in a message. These URL's can be passed in various formats

```
www.google.com    

https://www.google.com   

<a href = www.google.com>GOOGLE</a> 

<a href = "https://www.google.com">GOOGLE</a>
```

I'm attempting to use Pattern and Matcher but the `find()` method doesn't recognize if I have already replaced a substring of my string. Can you guys take a look at my logic and give me some advice please.

Thank You

Code Below:

```
  String link = url;
            if (!html.contains("@" + url) && !html.contains(url + "@")) {
                if (!(link.contains("http:") || link.contains("https:"))) {
                    link = "https://" + url;
                }
                String href = "<a href=\"" + link.toLowerCase() + "\">";

                String begin = href;
                String end = "</a>";

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a href(\\s?)*=(\\s?)*\"(\\s?)*(.?)*www.(.)*\"[^>]*>.*</a>");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
                if (!matcher.find()) {
                        html = html.replace(matcherUrl.group(), begin + link + end);
                    } else {
                        html = html.replace(matcherUrl.group(), link);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return html;
```

The string `html` is an entire message....for example

```
        val html = "HTML-Http: <a href = \"https://www.google.com\">GOOGLE</a> \n
 HTML-noHttp: <a href = \"www.google.com\">GOOGLE</a> \n
 URL-http: https://www.google.com \n
 URL-noHttp: www.google.com"
```

Comment: Something like that? https://regex101.com/r/TTrOCd/1

Comment: Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Well that regex expression correctly identifies a url, however my issue was correctly parsing url links and linkifying all of them. There doesnt really seem a nice way to do this, the regex you provided did help me find a temporary solution that works in most cases though.

Comment: I am glad my suggestion could help you. Do you want me to post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes that is fine